# Should I create namespaces for Entities and Value Objects?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am building an application using DDD principles.  I am now thinking about the namespace structure in the core of my application.  Please see the idea below:

```
Company.Application.Core.Entities
Company.Application.Core.ValueObjects
```

However, I cannot find a single example of an application on GitHb, which follows this convention.  Is there a specific reason not to follow this naming convention?

I also have a base class for entities i.e. `Company.Application.Core.Entities.Entity` and a base class for value objects i.e. `Company.Application.Core.ValueObjects.ValueObject`

The alternative option is to put all Value Objects and Entities in: `Company.Application.Core`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach will work, but such composition tells story about your code focused on DDD Building Blocks, not about immanent features of your domain. In DDD we want to show important things about domain, the technology issues are not the most important concerns anymore.

I suggest creating following namespaces:

```
YourCompany.YourApplicationName.YourParticularBoundedContextName.Application
```

here you can keep all Application Scope building blocks i.e. Application Services and DTO's which are used to transfer parameters to Application Services and return data from them.

```
YourCompany.YourApplicationName.YourParticularBoundedContextName.Domain
```

this is the namespace where you will create subnamespaces for Domain Scope building blocks.

```
YourCompany.YourApplicationName.YourParticularBoundedContextName.Domain.AggregateName
```

each Aggregate have its own namespace in which there are Aggregate Root class, Entities and VOs used internally in this Aggregate, Repository interface, Aggregate Factory if needed etc.
I don't know if in C# it is possible, but in Java there is another advantage of having separate package (namespace) for Aggregate - you can make Aggregate Root class public and all other Entities and VOs that are internally used as package scope, so they will not be visible outside package (namespace). This way you build public API for your Aggregate that no one can break, because there is a guardian: the compiler :)

```
YourCompany.YourApplicationName.YourParticularBoundedContextName.Infrastructure
```

here is a place for repositories' implementations (each in subnamespace of corresponding Aggregate)

Base classes can be kept in:

```
YourCompany.YourApplicationName.Domain
```

and even kept in separate project as you can try to reuse it in another application.

What is the advantage? When working with code you are focusing on features and domain rather than on technological aspects. You will more frequently have to cope with problems like "how does this process flow look like" than "I want to see all my Entities and VOs at once", so let your code structure support this. Separating Entities (Aggregates parts actually) and VOs (also Aggregate parts) into separate namespaces you lost information what is working with what. You can simple end with big ball of mud, because you will reuse something that shouldn't be reused.

Please look at:
https://github.com/BottegaIT/ddd-leaven-v2
it is a sample project in Java with packaging done this way. Maybe it will help you.

Another example is:
https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples
which is a sample for Vaughn Vernon's book about DDD.

There is also article that can be useful:
http://www.codingthearchitecture.com/2015/03/08/package_by_component_and_architecturally_aligned_testing.html

Answer (score 0):

Using separate namespaces for your Entity types (that map to database tables etc.) and your DTO types (used for passing data between client and server layers of your application) is pretty standard practice, even if `.Entities` and `.ValueObjects` aren't particularly common choices. I don't think it's worth worrying about too much as long as you use them consistently.

Comment: I am talking about the domain layer.  The domain layer is not even aware of the database.  Therefore I do not understand what you mean.